# Angular2 Routing: Combine url sections to one parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Is it possible to combine url sections into one parameter? E.g. I have urls `/products/123/234/345`, `/products/123/235` and `/products/125`. I have a route with `path : 'products/:key'`.  Now I want the key to be `123/234/345` for the first url, `123/235` for the second url and `125` for the last url. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm almost sure it is not possible. If someway it is possible, I beg you, please don't do that. We have to develop in a way that everyone understands what you are doing, that kind of thing is a mess. If it was a problem of mine, I would re-design it.

Comment: no, but you can define three routes: [path : 'products/:key', path : 'products/:key1/key2', path : 'products/:key1/key2/key3'] for a single component and access these parameters inside the component

Comment: @Maximus the useof 3 keys is most likely an example, thomas surelly wants to concatenate n ids into one array route parameter

Comment: Yes, it was an example. The user can create products and give them ids. The ids can contain language ids, group ids, static strings and can be created dynamically. Is it possible to route everything with /products to component A and everything with /products/** to component B, read the url and extract the last part of the url

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of it, you can't do that by using Angular2 router. The only way I see that you could try is to define 3 paths corresponding to your use cases, as already explained by Maximus :

```
[path : 'products/:key', path : 'products/:key1/key2', path : 'products/:key1/key2/key3']
```

If this doesn't solve your problem, you should maybe reconsider the way you are trying to build your app as this is Angular2 way to build routes and any onther tricky way should be avoided.